# Can a 64 bit EXE link against 32-bit DLLs?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, dll

I ask because I noticed that many 64 bit EXEs link against what appear to be 32-bit DLLs.

For example, my 64 bit MFC app links against `user32.dll, urlmon.dll, wininet.dll` - all of which are 32 bit DLLs that reside in windows\system32.

So is this some MS specific wizardry that applies to these DLLs, or is there backward compatability, as it were, for 64 bit EXEs that need to use legacy 32 bit DLLs?

Comment: I think we are all ready for the next version of Dependency Walker. It handles 64 bit executables in a sometimes misleading way, and shows some other annoying warnings. Those are not really bugs, but sure can be better presented. I think these kind of questions are a +1 for a new version.

Comment: @Eran, I downloaded the latest depends for 64 bit and it shows the dependent DLLs as 64.

Comment: There is actually some wizardry -- on Win64 the 64-bit ntdll.dll gets loaded into ALL processes, both 32-bit and 64-bit.  But nothing magic about any of the DLLs you mentioned.

Comment: https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot link 64-bit EXEs to 32-bit DLLs or vice versa. On a 64-bit Windows OS, the DLLs in Windows\System32 are actually 64-bit DLLs. The 32-bit versions are in Windows\SysWow64.

Comment: If "depends" is a 32-bit program, then ssg's comment comes into play -- the WOW layer redirects 32-bit applications' view of the file system so that they see what's in SysWow64 as being in System32.

Comment: Wow, I always thought it the other way around. Interesting.

Answer (score 13):

Call 32 from 64, Sure It can. (In windows this is called WOW wich means Windows on Windows). But, viceversa It doesn't work.

Here you have the explanation of how:

http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Hope it serves.

Comment: It's a useful technique and it should actually work in both directions, but it's not really "linking against".

Comment: To be precise (and avoid disappointment), it's not really "Call 32 from 64", the "solution" described in the article just creates a surrogate 32-bit process and uses IPC to forward calls to it from a 64-bit process. "Call 32 from 64" directly is not possible (in user mode) as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Dependency Walker (found here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/) fixes this issue. It finds the correct DLLs, and avoids the inaccurate errors.

(I'm late to the party, but google still found this question when I had a similar problem.)