# 64bit property sheets are using 32bit winapi dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2015, 32bit-64bit

I converted an old visual studio project with vs2015 and added a 64bit platform configuration.

I wonder why the linker attributes does contain 32bit libs (like kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib).

First i thought this is a mistake by me, since i selected to copy the settings from the win32 platform settings but then I saw that this settings are imported by a property sheet that was inserted by the studio: "Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user"

Is this really the way how this should work? I read somewhere (here on SO: [Can a 64 bit EXE link against 32-bit DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116265/can-a-64-bit-exe-link-against-32-bit-dlls)) that a 64bit app cannot link against 32bit dlls.

Can somone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These DLL names date back 23 years ago when the first 32-bit version of Windows was released.  Windows versions 1 to 3 were 16-bit and used kernel.dll, user.dll, etcetera.  They glued "32" after the DLL name to distinguish them from the 16-bit versions and ensure that a 32-bit process can't load a 16-bit DLL by accident.

They did not do that again when they released the 64-bit version of Windows.  Too many programs hard-coded these names by then, typically in a LoadLibrary() call, and changing the names would have made it too difficult to port such programs to 64-bit.  Not even the directory where those DLLs are stored was renamed, it is still "system32".

So a machine now has two copies of kernel32.dll et al, the 64-bit version is located in c:\windows\system32 and the 32-bit version in c:\windows\syswow64.  It is still very important that a 32-bit process never attempts to load a 64-bit DLL, and the other way around, just like it was important 23 years ago.  So they came up with another trick, the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ensures that a 32-bit process can only ever see the copy in syswow64.

Do note the oddity of having 64-bit DLLs in a directory named "system32" and 32-bit DLLs in "syswow64".  Trips up many programmers at first, now you know how that happened.

Much the same for the .lib files, the SDK directory has an x86 and a x64 directory to store these files.  Also pretty much automatic, where the linker looks for the .lib file is configured in Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories.  A Win32/x86 platform target uses $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86) and an x64 target uses $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64).

Comment: ahh - ok - i see. I also was irritated by the dependency walker (2.1.xx), that showed the exe to be 64bit but the dependent dlls not. with an updated version (2.2.xxx) the dependencies are also marked as 64bit - contrary to their names (as you also explained)